# Are there built-in developer tools for speech recognition in iOS?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

How can I detect that speech was started from some audio file. I need only detect start and stop of the speech without recognition
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this app

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

you can tinker with this sample code a little to get what you need...

Here is one more link that I have come across

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pitch detector to listen for the presence of harmonic tones within the range of human speech.  I don't know of any pitch detector for iOS though. I wrote my own And it was very hard.

Dirac does pitch detection, I don't know how accurate it is because I don't want to spend £1000 on the licence.